# JPA - Error create table using DDL generation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make a simple Spring application but I have trouble when I pass from H2 database to MySQL.

Here is my properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The entity that doesn't work:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Option")
public class Option {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;

    @Column(name = "option", length = 1000, nullable = false)
    private String option;

    @Column(name = "is_right", nullable = false)
    private boolean isRight;

}
```

And the error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table option (id bigint not null, is_right bit not null, option varchar(1000) not null, question_id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at ....
```

What is wrong ? I have nothing special or tricky in my entity

Answer (score 0):

I solve my error by myself,
Option is a keyword in MySql that's why it didn't work